# Graphing with JLabel for looks [null layout] Java Swing *ERROR

Tags: java, swing, interface, helper

I am trying to build a student graph with JLabels

my app does a sql query and returns an int value for each month's number of entries and if doesnt find any it returns 0.

```
//scale variable is an int

//ene is a return value from another method that runs before

//in case there are no students in january I dont have to graph anything
//so this 'if' doesnt run

Scale = 50;  

if (Ene != 0) { 

            System.out.println(Ene + " ene stdds");

// this prints out 11 ene stdds

            double EneBH = 449 * (Ene / Scale);
            int EneBHeight = (int) Math.round(EneBH);
            int EneBYLocal = 612 - EneBHeight;

            EneP.setBounds(76, EneBYLocal, 7, EneBHeight);
            EneP.setVisible(true);

        } else {

//if the last if didnt run I want to know if it hidd the label

            System.out.println("HIDDEN ENE");
            EneP.setVisible(false);
        }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/su4qS.png]

*Ene P is the very first jlabel for graphing, it looks kida gray and is at the enero zone.

*EneP prints out 11 students but never shows up, doesnt print hidden ene, it just doesnt show up

*EneP will have the same code than the other jlabels if I solve it or you solve it, please

Comment: Sorry, I could't see a question in your question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (And ask a question.)

Answer (score 0):

**I have found a Solution for My Own Problem**

The solution was easy turns out that If you divide Ene (the return variable from a query that saves as an integer value) by the Scale variable which is also an integer it causes java to return 0

So I have discovered this on my own by placing a system.out.print() after every line and printing the values of every variable.

I noticed 11/50 shouldn't return 0, so I changed the scale variable to be a double and still returned 0; but I changed both and now it works just right.

```
Scale = 50;  

if (Ene != 0) { 

        System.out.println(Ene + " ene stdds");

// this prints out 11 ene stdds

        double EneBH = 449 * (Ene / Scale);
        int EneBHeight = (int) Math.round(EneBH);
        int EneBYLocal = 612 - EneBHeight;

        EneP.setBounds(76, EneBYLocal, 7, EneBHeight);
        EneP.setVisible(true);

    } else {

  //if the last if didnt run I want to know if it hidd the label

        System.out.println("HIDDEN ENE");
        EneP.setVisible(false);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaOQR.png)